# R join markers on map with lines using Leaflet

Tags: r, google-maps, leaflet, overlay

How would you go about joining two point on a map together. This is my code at the moment:

```
library(leaflet)

data=read.csv('/Users/reubenmatthew/Documents/JourneyPlan.csv')
m=leaflet() %>%
  addTiles() %>%  # Add default OpenStreetMap map tiles
  addCircleMarkers(lng=(data$Start_long[18:30]), lat=(data$Start_lat[18:30]), popup="Start") %>%
  addMarkers(lng=(daat$End_long[18:30]), lata=(dat$End_lat[18:30]),popup="End")  
print(m)  # Print the map
```

and this is what the output looks like:
[image]

as you can see it is pretty hard to see what the start and end points are without the connecting lines

Comment: hello  use `addPolylines`  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32275213/how-do-i-connect-two-coordinates-with-a-line-using-leaflet-in-r

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32275213/how-do-i-connect-two-coordinates-with-a-line-using-leaflet-in-r